# How to read a website &save har data iteratively(I have CSV file with 1000 URLS-but can't save files with unique name

Tags: python, selenium, har

Aim of this project: test 10 adblocker in browser's plug-in,and run in 1000 retrieve 1000 har data for 1 adblocker. so total data set will be 10X1000(test data)+1000 (original data) = 11000.

The script run smoothly in reading 1 urls and save 1.har. However, I have a list of CSV with 1000 urls, what i want is to  run the urls from csv and save 1-1000.har respectively without overwrite.

However, I cannot link to save part. When i launch program, the browser just keep loading different urls but just only save 1 har data file.

```
import csv
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver
import json
server = Server("D:\\browsermob-proxy-2.1.4\\bin\\browsermob-proxy.bat")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

extension_dir = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\features\\"

# remember to include .xpi at the end of your file names 
extensions = [
    'adblock_plus-3.5-an+fx.xpi'
    ]

for extension in extensions:
    driver.install_addon(extension_dir + extension, temporary=True)
    proxy.new_har("qq")

path = "D:\websites.csv"    
csvfile = open(path,'r')
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
result = {}
for item in reader:
    if reader.line_num ==1:
        continue
    result[item[0]] = item[1]

csvfile.close()
print(result)


for id, web in result.items():
    website = web
    driver.get(website)




server.stop()
driver.quit()


f = os.fdopen(fi, "w")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why can't you save the `proxy.har` to a file with required name for each url.

Comment: Saving har is not a problem, but automatically visit 1000 urls and save 1000 har with unique name is the problem.

Comment: You had the right logic before updating the post, looping through each result `web`, but make sure to `proxy.new_har(web)` in this loop before `driver.get(web)` . Then dump the 'proxy.har' response to json and open a file with `web + "_har.har"` and write the json dump in there.